# Confidence Intervals over time on expectation of having covid$-19$?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I have the random indicator variable $X$, which takes $1$ if the person has covid and $0$ otherwise. I have calculated $Prob(X_i = 1)$ (so the ${E[X_i]}$or expectation of $X_i$) over the course of $137$ days.

The next question is to "Derive confidence intervals for your estimates of $Prob(X_0 = 1)$ using the CLT and Chebyshev Inequality and plot these confidence intervals vs time, e.g. as error bars about the estimates of $Prob(X_0 = 1)$."

So I got my array of $E[X_i]$ values, and for each day I calculated the mean and standard deviation based on that day and all previous days and then did my calculations.

This leads to $95\%$ confidence intervals that seem to grow and grow ([graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5CVl.jpg)) Is this correct? what does this imply? Is it not incorrect to create confidence intervals on this time based sampling anyways???

Comment: This is not clear.  You have almost defined $X$, but you never defined $X_i$ at all.  But even $X$...are you talking about a single day?  Some longer period of time?  If the latter, presumably we are to assume some dependence between the results of various days, no?  What, exactly, does $P(X_i=1)$ mean?

Comment: If you really mean to have independence between days then are you speaking of a routine binomial process or something else?  If this is just a binomial process, then standard techniques should apply, no?  But, really, independence between the days seems very unphysical.

Comment: Xi is an indicator random variable that takes 1 when the i’th person tests positive. So P(Xi = 1) would be the probability that a person tests positive. Each day there is a number of people who test positive. I calculated P(Xi = 1) over 137 days and that is the blue bars. I'm now uncertain on how you create a confidence interval for P(Xi = 1), it seems fairly straight forward but I'm not sure what exactly my result implies or if it is correct

Comment: What do you mean you "calculated $P(X_i=1)$ over $137$ days"?  You tested the same person every day for $137$ days and measured...what exacty?

Comment: This is all very vague.  What data are you given?  What is it you want to calculate?

Comment: the "test" is on the entire population and is 100% accurate so its really just the probability that a randomly picked person in the population has covid. I calculated this for a number of days and graphed it.

Comment: If I know the result for the entire population then I know whether person $i$ has the virus or not, so there is no probability involved.  If you didn't mean to refer to a single individual at all, then I can use the population to get an exact value for the probability that a randomly selected individual has the virus, but again that computation is exact.  I think you must have some model in mind that you are trying to fit parameters to, and you want to use some sample data to estimate those parameters...but you don't give us any information on the model you are thinking of.

Comment: To stress my earlier points:  Probabilities involved in epidemiology are subtle, for lots of reasons.  One of those reasons is independence.  Presumably in your model (and in your data), once a person has the virus, they continue to have it for a while, after which they might be immune to it. Or they succumb to the illness and drop out of the pool that way...but that doesn't seem like a good way to handle it either. That tends to mess up naive measures for probability...so people can speak of "new" cases, or some other measure which excludes those already known to have been infected.